# Python multivariable nonlinear regression calculation

Tags: python

i was trying to make a curve fit of data and want to find nonlinear regression equation.

[image]

thats what my plot looks like i got x,y data which will be my reference data,
then i got x0 and y0 which will be my second point,
dx and dy will be difference between them
when i show this as vector it showed form of

[image]

when i convert dx,dy to R and theta it showed x^2+y^2 form,
is it possible to find those equation with it?
here's my current code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
import seaborn as sns
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
"""setting dpi for graph shown in editor"""
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 300

import pandas as pd
"""reading data from excel sheet 1"""
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\JRKIM\Desktop\data\2513data.xlsx')

"""variable selection"""

tx_0 = df.loc[:,'TRUE_x_0']
ty_0 = df.loc[:,'TRUE_y_0']

v_x_0 = df.loc[:,'vx']
v_y_0 = df.loc[:,'vy']

dx0_0 = tx_0-v_x_0
dy0_0 = ty_0-v_y_0

dr0_0 = df.loc[:,'dr']




fig1, ax0 = plt.subplots()
ax0.set_title("delta0 in vector")

qk = ax0.quiver(tx_0,ty_0,dx0_0,dy0_0)
ax0.scatter(tx_0, ty_0, color='r', s=1)

"""3d graph with vector and position """

fig4 = plt.figure()
ax4 = fig4.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax4.scatter(tx_0, ty_0, dr0_0, marker='*',linewidth = 0.01, cmap="jet")

ax4.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax4.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax4.set_zlabel('dr Label')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [scipy.optimize.curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) as follows.

```py
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def quadratic_function(x, a, b):
    return a * x[0]**2 + b * x[1]**2 # + c * x[0]*x[1] if you want to satisfy quadratic form

xdata = np.vstack([np.array(dx0_0).flatten(),np.array(dy0_0).flatten()])
ydata = np.array(dr0_0).flatten()
popt, pcov = curve_fit(quadratic_function,xdata,ydata)
print(popt) # values for a and b
```

this should get you the coefficients for a and b for the least squares fitting of `a*x**2 + b*y**2 = r`, you have to further calculate the error and see if the error is low enough for your liking.

**Edit:** corrected the dimensions of inputs